# I do not understand the PHP "Daily quote" tutorial

Tags: php, random, seed

In [this tutorial](http://webhostinghelpguy.inmotionhosting.com/web-hosting/php-tricks-for-beginners/) in the part of Daily inspirations he says:

```
$quote = array(
1 => "Quote 1",
2 => "Quote 2",
3 => "Quote 3",
4 => "Quote 4",
5 => "Quote 5",
);
srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$randnum = rand(1,5);
echo"$quote[$randnum]";
```

I do not understand what he is doing (literally) here:

```
srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
```

Could you please help me understand what this does?

I know [srand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) is to:

> Seed the random number generator

But why does he do this, what's the point of it?

By the way: I would have gone with something like this:

```
<?php

$quotes = array(

"one",
"two",
"three"

);

echo $quotes[rand(0,count($quotes)-1)];
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: it's just a thingy about being really random or not... http://www.capuzza.com/detail.php?ID=115293

Comment: @andre matos that is from 2007 I looks that it is no really necessary any more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368616/do-not-understand-php-daily-quote-tutorial/4368656#4368656 THanks!!

Comment: You're right, but that was all I knew about it (really outdated here!!). That's why I posted as a comment and not as a real answer! I feel so much more enlightened now! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most random number generators [aren't actually random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator); the next number they generate is calculated using a simple-yet-large function from previous numbers that have been generated. Seeding the RNG gives it a "previous" number to work from, since many times they start from the same known state each time.

Answer (score 4):

Before PHP 4.2 you needed to 'seed' the randomizer in order for it to actually be 'random.'  Now it's pointless to seed the randomizer.

The docs state:

> Note: As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no
>   need to seed the random number
>   generator with srand() or mt_srand()
>   as this is now done automatically.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php

Your solution is just as effective.

Comment: @Darryl E. Clarke, So, bottom line, no longer necessary! Thanks!

Comment: With or without specify the seed, in any PHP version (or in any other language, for that matter) you will NEVER have random numbers, as they are always derived in a deterministic way from the seed.

Comment: @nico TRUE! thanks! learned that here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness

Comment: @nico - agreed.  But that's not really the topic here.

Comment: @Darryl E. Clarke: sure, I was just pointing out (forgetting for a second about the differences between PHP versions) that the numbers generated after calling `srand` are no more or no less random than those generated without calling `srand`. In fact, the term pseudo-random should be preferred.

Comment: and, by the way, as nobody seems to have linked it yet (what a shame!), here's the compulsory Dilbert comic: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind calling `srand()` is to provide "better" random numbers. But it is not necessarily true that calling `srand()` brings "more random" numbers. Since `PHP 4.2` it is not essential to call `srand()` because PHP does this internal.

Answer (score 2):

This simply is an artifact from a twenty-year-old tutorial (*use another one!*):

- The random number generator is [seeded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) automatically already for a very long time
- [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/mt_rand) should be preferred over `rand`, as it is faster and "more random" (i.e. it gives unbiased random variables in more degrees)

PS: I would recommend using [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand) here, because you don't need to care about the exact keys.

```
echo $quotes[array_rand($quotes)];
```

Comment: Yep, knew it was old. Thanks for `mt_rand`!!

Comment: @Trufa: @BTW: Your code is way better when theirs. The usage of a 0-indexed array is definitely better and using the more generic `length` is better too. But as noted in my post you could even make it more generic by using `array_rand` ;)

Comment: that looks better and is a great short cut, thanks!! but I could not get what you ment by `you will need to change the 5 in the script` what would I have to change?? thanks again!!