# Using system time directly to get random numbers

Tags: time, random

I had to return a random element from an array so I came up with this placeholder:

```
return codes[(int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % codes.length - 1)];
```

Now than I think of it, I'm tempted to use it in real code. The `Random()` seeder uses system time as seed in most languages anyway, so why not use that time directly? As a bonus, I'm free from the worry of non-random lower bits of many RNGs. It this hack coming back to bite me? (The language is Java if that's relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in java.util.Random. Item 47 of **Effective Java** (second edition, page 215) brings this up as an example of why you should prefer the standard libraries over rolling your own. It begins by explaining that `Math.abs(rnd.nextInt() % n` is a bad approach, since it doesn't yield a truly random distribution and that you should simply use `rnd.nextInt(n)` instead. It goes on to say:

> To write a version of the `random` method that corrects these three
>   flays, you'd have to know a fair
>   amount about pseudorandom number
>   generators, number theory, and two's
>   complement arithmetic.
>
> ...
>
> You don't have to concern yourself with the details of how `nextInt(int)` does it job. A senior engineer with a background in algorithms spent a good deal of time designing, implementing, and testing this method and then showed it to several experts in the field to make sure it was right. Then the library was beta tested, released, and used extensively by millions of programmers for the better part of a decade. No flaws have yet been found in the method, but if a flaw were to be discovered, it would be fixed in the next relase. By using a standard library, you take advantage of the knowledge of the experts who wrote it and the experience of those who used it before you.

It should be noted that even though the example doesn't use exactly the same code as the one you're suggesting, it's even more true for your example. Taking the remainder of a random integer skews the distribution, but at least it has some appearence of randomness. Just moding the time is an even worse approach.

You underestimate the complexity of pseudo random number generators. The problem with the approach that you're suggesting is that not only is it possible that the distribution is far from random, but moreover, it will be really predictable. There are realworld examples of hackers exploiting pseudorandom number generators with predictable seeds to cheat at poker. **Building secure software** (Viega and McGraw, 2002) contains a full chapter discussing these issues.

> Here's a good example of how poor PRNGs can be broken in practice. In 1999, the Software Security Group at Cigital discovered a serious flaw in the implementation of Texas Hold 'em Poker, which is distributed by ASF Software, Inc. The exploit allowed a cheating player to calculated the exact deck being used for each hand in real time. This means that a player using the exploit knows the cards in every opponent's hand as well as the cards that make up the flop (cards placed face up on the table after rounds of betting). A cheater can "know when to hold 'em and know when to fold 'em" every time. A malicious attacker could use the exploit to bilk innocent players of actual money without every being caught. (Page 238)

Here's two questions that discusses the complexity of randomness:

- [Understanding randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness)
- [Expand a random range from 1-5 to 1-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7)

This is a paper that's only a few weeks old (but with a really lame title) describing how you could attack the session generation algorithm of PHP by utilizing the predictable seed of the PRNG:

- [How I met your girlfriend](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-10/whitepapers/Kamkar/BlackHat-USA-2010-Kamkar-How-I-Met-Your-Girlfriend-wp.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible idea! Don't even think about it! Successive calls to this home-grown 'pseudorandom number generator' will be correlated so strongly that you might as well just be using a simple counter. (Which, in case you missed it, I don't recommend.)

**Edited to add:** By the way, as you've coded it, your array index will occasionally be -1. This is also a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of against this is: What if the system clock always returns a multiple of 16 (this can happen on windows XP machines, for example), and your array happens to be of length 16?

Answer (score 0):

There are generally good reasons for standard library classes to have been developed in the first place.

While it may be cool to experiment with writing your own code to tackle problems in an academic setting, in a business setting it's best to use tried and tested libraries and techniques that are less likely to create unwanted behavior in your application.

If you are set on using your technique, I would strongly suggest you write thorough test cases to test boundary conditions and a large set of data points.  This will help you debug your code before it hits production.