# Randomized location isn't random [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, random

I made a randomization function for my regen and it just makes all the things that respawn in a diagonal line across the form... the code is this:

```
Public Function RandomNumber(ByVal MaxNumber As Integer, _
Optional ByVal MinNumber As Integer = 0) As Integer

    'initialize random number generator
    Dim r As New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)

    'if passed incorrect arguments, swap them
    'can also throw exception,return 0

    If MinNumber > MaxNumber Then
        Dim t As Integer = MinNumber
        MinNumber = MaxNumber
        MaxNumber = t
    End If

    Return r.Next(MinNumber, MaxNumber)

End Function
```

and the code for 1 regen is this:

```
'regen coins
        z = coin1
```

`z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()`

I do not know why it just makes a diagonal line but help would be VERY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'm going to make a suggestion. Initialize your random number generator outside the RandomNumber function. Otherwise you create a new instance every time you make a call:

```
'initialize random number generator outside the function 
Public _r As New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)

Public Function RandomNumber(ByVal MaxNumber As Integer, Optional ByVal MinNumber As Integer = 0) As Integer
    ' ensure min is less than max
    If MinNumber > MaxNumber Then
        Return _r.Next(MaxNumber, MinNumber)
    Else
        Return _r.Next(MinNumber, MaxNumber)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thank you..but now the things spawn in objects how do i stop that?

Comment: I'd suggest changing If zloc.Y > 595 Then to a loop rather than a single test. `Do While zloc.Y > 595 : zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height)) : Loop `

Comment: would this work to stop it from being inside picturebox1, picturebox2, and picturebox3?                                                                                              z = coin1



        z.Location = zloc
        z.Hide()
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
        Do While z.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox1.Bounds, PictureBox2.Bounds, PictureBox3.Bounds)
            zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
        Loop
        z.Location = zloc
        z.Show()

Comment: Rather than appending your next question to this one, I think you need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Random` object, `r`, has function-level scope, which means that you re-initialize it upon each entry to the `RandomNumber` function.

A lot of people make this mistake and get the same "random" value each time<sup>*</sup>. You do get a slightly different number each time because, instead of using the default constructor, you're re-initializing it with a semi-random seed (the current millisecond count from the clock). Either way, the call to `r.Next()` is still not doing what you want it to do.

To fix this, ensuring that it's the same `Random` object that is used on each call to the function, **hoist the declaration of `r` up a scope level (e.g., to the containing class), or mark it [`Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) at function-level.**

That will probably help enough to make you happy. If not, you're in for more education than you were probably hoping. The topic of *randomness* is a big philosophical one. There is no better place to start than [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) on the subject, or perhaps [this famous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness).

<sub><sup>*</sup> Which is, of course, entirely allowed within the definition of "random". It's just not what people are wanting.</sub>