# How to find the probability density function of a function of normal distribution and draw a graph of it

Tags: math, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I know the pdf of standard normal distribution, but what's the pdf of a function of it?
For example: standard normal distribution + 1, how should I find the pdf? I think the graph for this one is easier, just move the graph up by 1.

Comment: Be careful to move the graph by 1 in the correct direction ;-)

Comment: Also note that "a function of a pdf" and "the pdf of a function of a random variable following a pdf" are not the same thing.

Comment: @Stef You got me there, I think I'm asking the function of pdf, like Z is std and I want to find the formula for probability density of  Z + 1

Comment: @Stef Thanks I think I should move the graph to the right, but I'm still confused about formula, could you give more hint on that?

Comment: see [Understanding “randomness”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956538/2521214) for some ideas ... you can simply measure the `pdf(f(prng))` by simply doing histogram of outputted PRNG numbers and plot it as graph... and or fit it with some curve or equation